# dumb-jump finds all references instead of definitions

Tags: search

Example code:

```
typedef int my_type_t;

my_type_t a;

my_type_t my_function(my_type_t in)
{
    return (my_type_t) 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    my_type_t b;
    a = my_function(b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `dump-jump-go` on `my_type_t`, it finds all references to the type, instead of the type definition:

[image]

This is not what I expect after reading the documentation. The same happens with functions: definitions, declarations, and calls pop up.

---

Installing the dumb-jump package from elpa gave the following warnings, but I'm not sure they matter:

```
dumb-jump.el:1475:1:Warning: Unused lexical argument `proj'
dumb-jump.el:1622:1:Warning: Unused lexical argument `config'
dumb-jump.el:2251:1:Warning: Unused lexical argument `cur-file'
dumb-jump.el:2300:1:Warning: Unused lexical argument `exclude-paths'
dumb-jump.el:2300:1:Warning: Unused lexical argument `lang'

In end of data:
dumb-jump.el:2372:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined: ivy-read,
    helm-build-sync-source
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no regex to find type definitions like this in the c/c++ dumb-jump rules. So `dumb-jump-fallback-search` is kicking in, which by default will just look for the symbol. You can undo this behavior by using `(setq dumb-jump-fallback-search nil)`.

There is more context on related things in this [dumb-jump GitHub issue](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump/issues/213).

Comment: I'm the creator of the issue, are you jacktasia?

Comment: Yup, I am the dumb-jump guy. I came across this question randomly.  I added the link purely for other people that come across this issue since they're related.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
(setq dumb-jump-prefer-searcher 'ag)
```

seemed to help, although dumb-jump's manual mentions it should use `git-grep` anyway:

> (setq dumb-jump-prefer-searcher 'rg) to let Dumb Jump know your
>   searcher preference. If set this will still use git-grep if it's a git
>   project (because it's the fastest), but will you use whatever you set
>   here in any other situation. If not set Dumb Jump will follow the same
>   order as mentioned in the dumb-jump-force-searcher description. At
>   this time setting this value is only necessary if you prefer rg but
>   have ag installed too.

Not manually setting up dumb-jump to use `ag` also seemed to choose an alternative file definition aggressively, discarding the definition in the same file.